# Visual Studio IDE will not restore after being minimized

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After I minimize My Visual Studio IDE, it is visible on the task bar, but will not restore when selected.  I am forced to close the instance of Visual Studio and restart.  This is an obvious pain.

Other applications on machine do not suffer this problem.

Environment is Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7, 64 bit OS.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Jim

Comment: Can you right click on the icon in the taskbar and select restore? Does that work?

Comment: No.  When I right-click in the task bar restore is not there.  Just a 'Recent' list, 'Visual Studio 2010' option, 'Pin this program to taskbar' option, and 'Close Window' option.

Comment: This might sound extreme, but that sounds really strange to me, maybe try re-installing VS and if that doesn't work the whole OS.  Try to find an answer first though just in case it's something small.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the suggestion to right-click on the taskbar and select restore.  That works.  The original issue still exists, but this is a workaround that I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use multiple monitors?  If so it could be that when clicked on the Visual Studio IDE is opening up outwith the space of the current monitors?  I had this same problem with my Novell mail client.

Comment: I do not have multiple monitors.